# Grind a quartz counter top or call a Pro?

Tags: sink, quartz

I'm looking to replace the sink in my quartz countertop.
The new sink I've purchased is a drop in sink of the same dimensions. 
It "fits" into the hole, with the exception that on both the left and right side of the sink are a couple tabs. So the sink fits into the hole, except for the tabs. These tabs sit under the lip, but would require notching out the counter in 4 spots by about 1/8". The sink would almost fit in like a puzzle piece.

I want to understand the risk of getting a grinder and doing this myself. Is there a chance of really messing up my counter top? Is this a DIY job, or call a Pro due to the complexity and mess?

Tabs under the sink:
The instructions/cutout is a rectangle with 4 sides. It doesn't move out/in to follow around the tabs. The hole to cut would take into account the size of these tabs. Thus, if installing new, the whole would just be bigger than the one I have now. Instead of making the entire hole bigger, I'm hoping to cheat and notch the counter top for these tabs under the lip. These tabs are for clamping the sink.

I cannot find the install instructions online (it's just the 1 large page cutout diagram), but this is the sink: https://www.blanco.com/ca-en/sinks/vision-f/vision-210-silgranit--pdp-59.046/

I've added a picture of the tabs. They are **not removable** Looking at the picture and thinking a bit more about this --- if I were to only notch out for these tabs, that means the sink would most likely be resting on the counter top on the **dark/black** material. The grey lip would not sit down flush, and thus there would be a gap. So my original question is slightly different, I originally thought about grinding out a 4 small parts for the tabs, now it seems I really do need to widen the hole. Is this a job for a Pro?

[image]

Comment: Ordinarily some sort of tab holds the sink down to the counter top.
These tabs are not attached when dropping in, but afterwards.  
See if they can be removed and re-attached.
Perhaps you should look into the sink manufacturers installation instructions.

Comment: A picture of the sink and tab would help.  The new sink has a top flange that overlaps the countertop all the way around the rim of the sink?

Comment: Thanks for the comments - have added some more information about these tabs. If necessary I can pull the sink out of the box and take a picture.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the vendor and asking them how this is supposed to be attached to a counter top, in particular, a quartz counter top. It looks like the 2 little holes are to accept screws that go through some sort of mounting plate attached from below. In that case, you would definitely need to cut through the countertop to allow the screws through, but ask **_BEFORE_** beginning to cut - just to be safe.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that the hole needs to be significantly widened. It looks to me as thought the sink should be resting on the lighter grey colored lip and not the dark/black area.

Comment: Yes the sink is design to rest on the light gray outline,  if the hole only allows the sink to rest on the dark portion, then a gap would exist between the flange and the countertop.

Comment: Thanks all for the confirmation - any guidance on my question? Can a novice with a diamond blade on a grinder do it in place, or am I asking for too much trouble?

Comment: would you be able to attach the sink on the underside of the counter slab?

Comment: Good ideal jsotola.  the countertop opening would have to be finished off, i.e., the edges smoothed, the only real issue would be the corners, Are the corners in good enough condition to be rounder.

Comment: This particular sink could be under mounted. But I went this with sink originally as I know the cut wasn't finished real nice, thus the path of least resistance would be a replacement, drop-in. If I was going to undermount, I'd go get the sink specific for that. Thanks for the thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, “Can a novice ..do it in place”.  Yes you could, but I would NOT.  The hole for the sink is normally cut out before the countertop is installed, with water flowing on the quartz as it is being cut.  All the mess is made outside.  I just had this done recently. 
I have done major DIY project, consider myself capable with a power handsaw.  I just cut up 4 leftover quartz countertops for an outdoor cabinet.  Since this in your kitchen, you would have to use a dry cut diamond blade, and it will be dusty as h…  I believe it will be difficult to cut the parallel line next to the backsplash and a saw guides will be difficult to clamp on the countertop except for the front edge.

A grinder would not have any support during your cutting session and would likely bind in the kerf as you proceed.  With the power handsaw, I was able to use a guide to keep the blade straight and on the cut line.
I believe the Pro would have better tools and blades to do this cut on an installed countertop and the router bit to do the corners of the sink cutout.

Again, I would NOT attempt to do this.  Any screwup and you are having to replace the whole countertop or a section of it with all the issues of making it match.

Comment: Fair answer, thank you for sharing your experience.